# does apportable support for Parse and messageUI?

Tags: parse-platform, apportable

Im currently working on porting a project to android with apportable, does anybody know if they support the messageUI framework, or if theres a list somewhere of the most current supported frameworks?

also, does anyone know if parse works with apportable?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software features/compatibility. This information is likely to change. Contact framework developer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of June 2014:

- `MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController` is partially implemented and available in the Apportable starter SDK
- `MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController` is not implemented
- Parse iOS API (circa November 2013) is also in the Apportable starter SDK, and there is a [sample project](https://github.com/apportable/Spin/tree/parse-sdk) that exercises it.  The code derives from [sbarron's ParseBridge](https://github.com/sbarron/ParseBridge).